# python gmail API: unable to send a simple mail

Tags: python, gmail-api

I modified very slightly the example from the API (https://github.com/googleworkspace/python-samples/blob/master/gmail/snippet/send%20mail/send_message.py), just to test the sending of a simple test email in python. I get the following error and I do not know how to correct this.

> "'raw' RFC822 payload message string or uploading message via /upload/* URL required". Details: "[{'message': "'raw' RFC822 payload message string or uploading message via  /upload/* URL required", 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'invalidArgument'}]"

> Python 3.9.7

Thank you for your time.

yann

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Copyright 2018 Google LLC
#
# Licensed under the Apache License, Version 2.0 (the "License");
# you may not use this file except in compliance with the License.
# You may obtain a copy of the License at
#
#     http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
#
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.

# [START gmail_quickstart]
from __future__ import print_function

import os.path

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2.credentials import Credentials
from google_auth_oauthlib.flow import InstalledAppFlow
from googleapiclient.discovery import build
from googleapiclient.errors import HttpError

import base64
import os

from email.mime.text import MIMEText

# If modifying these scopes, delete the file token.json.
SCOPES = ['https://mail.google.com/']


def gmail_send_message(creds):
    """Create and send an email message
    Print the returned  message id
    Returns: Message object, including message id
    Load pre-authorized user credentials from the environment.
    TODO(developer) - See https://developers.google.com/identity
    for guides on implementing OAuth2 for the application.
    """
    #creds, _ = google.auth.default()

    try:
        service = build('gmail', 'v1', credentials=creds)
        message = MIMEText('This is automated draft mail')
        message['To'] = 'recipient@gmail.com'
        message['From'] = 'sender@gmail.com'
        message['Subject'] = 'Automated draft'
        # encoded message
        encoded_message = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(message.as_bytes()).decode('utf8')

        print(encoded_message)
        create_message = {
            'message': {

                'raw': encoded_message
            }
        }
        # pylint: disable=E1101
        send_message = (service.users().messages().send
                        (userId="me", body=create_message).execute())
        print(F'Message Id: {send_message["id"]}')
    except HttpError as error:
        print(F'An error occurred: {error}')
        send_message = None
    return send_message


def main():
    """Shows basic usage of the Gmail API.
    """
    creds = None
    # The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    # created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    # time.
    if os.path.exists('token.json'):
        creds = Credentials.from_authorized_user_file('token.json', SCOPES)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(
                'key.json', SCOPES)
            creds = flow.run_local_server(port=0)
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.json', 'w') as token:
            token.write(creds.to_json())

    gmail_send_message(creds)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
# [END gmail_quickstart]
```

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing this:

```py
create_message = {'message': {'raw': encoded_message}}
```

to this:

```py
create_message = {'raw': encoded_message}
```

The rest seems right to me.

As you can see in the documentation, you don't need the  [message](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/reference/rest/v1/users.messages#resource:-message) key:

> The entire email message in an RFC 2822 formatted and base64url encoded string. Returned in messages.get and drafts.get responses when the format=RAW parameter is supplied.